# javascript input tag not setting id or class

Tags: javascript

I have a table with input rows created from a MySql query.  The user can alter those rows, but he/she might also wish to add a new row.  So I created a javascript function to add a new row when a button is clicked.  The new row is being created correctly, but the input tag is not getting its id or class.

```
  function addrow(id) {
  var tableref = document.getElementById(id);
  var nextseq  = document.getElementById('maxseq').value;

  var newRow = tableref.insertRow(2);
  var rowid  = "tr"+nextseq;
//first cell
 var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0) ;
 var text1 = document.createTextNode(nextseq);
 cell1.appendChild(text1);
 var id1   = "cell" + nextseq + "1"; 
 cell1.id = id1;

//second cell
var id2   = "cell" + nextseq + "2";             
var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = '<input type = "text" id = id2 class = "xxx"    style = "width:100px" value = "1001-01-01" >';
//  var test = document.getElementById(id2);
//alert("test is " + test); 


    ...more stuff which is working fine ...
 }
```

The alert on "test" gives 'test is null', so I gather the id is not being set.

I also tried

```
var abc = document.getElementsByClassName("xxx");
alert("abc is " + abc);
```

and the alert says abc is [object HTMLCollection]

How can I fix this so that the id and class are functioning?

Comment: id = "'+id2+'"  ... variable string concatenation

Answer (score 1):

Since id2 is a variable, you should use like this.

```
 var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = '<input type = "text" id =' + id2 + 'class = "xxx"    style = "width:100px" value = "1001-01-01" >';
```

Comment: Yep, that works.  However (see answer 2 below) my approach was not a good one because I need the id and class attached to the input tag,not the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to concatenation the variables into the string. JS does not have string interpolation.

```
var id2   = "cell" + nextseq + "2";             
var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = '<input type = "text" id = ' + id2 + ' class = "xxx"    style = "width:100px" value = "1001-01-01" >';
```

BUT BE AWARE that `cell2` holds the string, and not the new node. A nicer way to do this IMO is like this:

```
var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
var input = cell2.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
input.id = "cell" + nextseq + "2"; 
input.className = "xxx";
input.value = "1001-01-01";
```

I would then put the `width:100px;` style info in the CSS instead of on the element. But if it must be there, then:

```
input.style.width = "100px";
```

---

The `alert()` gives `[HTMLCollection]` because that's what's returned from `getElementsByClassName()`. Not sure what output you were looking for.

Comment: Hi dippity, Your second approach looks good because I do want the id and class attached to the input tag  I actually copied your code into my function, but it didn't operate.  Don't know why.  However, it did provide a clue, and I got something similar working.  Thanks.